# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push' in Angular js Http.get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-4, eloquent

Following is my controller, its really simple trying to pull data when a button is clicked, and trying to push it into ng-repeat.

```
 app.controller('HomeController',function($scope,$http) {

        $scope.user  = [];
        $scope.posts = [];
        $http.get('http://hashtag.dev/api/v1/user').success(function(data) {
            $scope.user = data;
        });
        $http.get('http://hashtag.dev/api/v1/post').success(function(data) {
            $scope.posts = data;
        });

        $scope.loadmore = function() {

            $http.get('http://hashtag.dev/api/v1/post').success(function(data) {
                $scope.posts.push(data);
            });
        };
    });
```

When the button with ng-click="loadmore()" is clicked

```
 TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'
```

What is wrong ? BTW i am a complete angular noob. JSON returned by server..

```
 {
"total": 37,
"per_page": 10,
"current_page": 2,
"last_page": 4,
"from": 11,
"to": 20,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 84,
        "user_id": 4,
        "post_text": "Sunt eius voluptatem nostrum eos eos ipsa qui. Laudantium ratione repudiandae vitae sunt distinctio earum.",
        "created_at": "2013-12-15 14:29:00",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "user": {
            "id": 4,
            "full_name": "Vinnie Lang",
            "username": "vinnie398",
            "created_at": "2013-12-15 14:28:54"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 82,
        "user_id": 2,
        "post_text": "Laudantium minus animi alias dolorum aperiam non. Odit quidem doloribus nihil eius incidunt sint nulla.",
        "created_at": "2013-12-15 14:29:00",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "user": {
            "id": 2,
            "full_name": "Shyanne Champlin",
            "username": "shyanne718",
            "created_at": "2013-12-15 14:28:53"
        }
    },...................
```

Comment: Put `console.log($scope.posts);` in loadmore and check your console.

Comment: Why is `$scope.posts = []` commented out? It seems to me that uncommenting it would fix the problem.

Comment: OH i did that still does not work , I am adding response which is JSON .

Comment: @Tejas - `console.log($scope)` - it should be an object with a `posts` array and a `user` array - is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `data` returned by your success callback to `$http.get('http://hashtag.dev/api/v1/post')` is an array of objects, you'd have to do:

1) define a `$scope.posts=[]` in your controller, just like you defined `$scope.user`

2) in the success callback of the `$http.get('http://hashtag.dev/api/v1/post')` in `loadmore()` you need to augment your `$scope.posts` with the new data:

```
$scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(data);
```

Comment: Now it says TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'concat',

Comment: @Tejas Did you define $scope.posts=[] at the beginning of the controller right after $scope.user=[] and is the returned `data` an array of objects, each corresponding to a post?

Comment: Seeing the JSON returned by server: the `data` in your success callback is the huge object you posted. From that you need the `.data` property which is an array of the posts (1 object / post). So do: `$scope.posts=data.data` in your 1st call to `$http.get('http://hashtag.dev/api/v1/post')` and in your `loadmore()` you augment the `$scope.posts` with `$scope.posts = $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(data.data)`

Comment: Yeah, It works now :) .BTW output is the JSON object returned by laravel's eloquent orm with pagination.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `$scope.posts` isn't an Array (or anything yet, you can't just `push` to an undefined variable and expect an Array to come of it). I would define an empty array in the beginning of the controller, or in the beginning of the callback:

```
$scope.posts = [];
```

Comment: Edited the question plz check

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**EDIT**

```
$scope.data = { posts : [] }

$scope.loadmore = function() {

    $http.get('http://hashtag.dev/api/v1/post').success(function(data) {
        $scope.data.posts.push.apply($scope.data.posts, data);
    });
};
```

Comment: You'd be emptying you're `posts` array every time you called `loadmore` instead of just adding to it.

Comment: Right ! its a mistake